# MVC Page routing replaces part of subdomain when subdomain text is also part of the route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I've got a strange problem with routing MVC paths to aspx pages. It all works find except for some rare scenario's. Actually not that rare as it's happened twice this month.

So We've got old aspx pages but we need to have friendlier URL's. That's the background, can't avoid it for reasons I won't go into.

So I have a page ~/MySubFolder/Plans.aspx

We need the URL to be ~/Things/Plans

so I have a page route in route config

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Tickets", "Things/Plans", "~/MySubFolder/Plans.aspx");
```

This all works fine in most circumstances.

The app is SaaS product and we determine the tenant in context based on the url they use. So each tenant gets a subdomain on our app like http://clienta.ourapp.com

So this is the problem.

We had a client sign up and they picked their subdomain to be http://plans.ourapp.com

The client does not have any problems except when they try to access our path ~/Things/Plans. when they do that we get an error. It's one of our own exceptions and it happens because on every request we determine who the tenant is by looking at the subdomain.

for some reason when we examine the domain name routing has stripped out the plans part of the sub domain name and is http:// .ourapp.com instead of http://plans.ourapp.com.

So this is obviously caused by the fact that the word **plans** is the subdomain and plans is also the end of the route Things/**Plans**

We need to somehow avoid this happening, maybe the route is not setup properly or maybe it's just a bug but would be great to figure out exactly why this is happening so we can fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out this had nothing to do with routing the URLs. Somewhere else in code where we try to evaluate the current tenants URL we were for some reason replacing part of the URL based on another part of the URL which was the problem in some scenarios. No wonder no-one had an answer for this